# Add overlay to image with CSS?

Tags: html, css, mobile, mobile-website

I have a image that I want to display a DIV on the bottom with some text. I know it's really easy, but since this is a mobile website and all the images are different sizes, I have to make it 100% width which makes everything messes everything up with you float images, etc.

This is what I have right now:

**HTML**

```
<div class='individual_picture_capption_wrapper'>
<div class='individual_picture_capption_wrapper_two'>
<div class='individual_picture_caption_wrapper_three'><div class='individual_picture_caption'>Some Caption Here</div></div>
<img src='http://myflashpics.com/get_image.php?short_string=8ibjr&size=big' class='individual_picture_big' />
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.individual_picture_caption {
    padding: 12px 10px 12px 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
}
.individual_picture_capption_wrapper {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.individual_picture_capption_wrapper_two {
    margin-left: 0px;
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
.individual_picture_caption_wrapper_three {
    float: left;
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url('http://myflashpics.com/viewer/images/transparent_black_70.png');
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin: 15px 30px 15px 15px;
}
```

My problem is that I want it to float on the bottom and the caption is hanging over the edge. I know it's because of my margin on the left.

Please help! I don't know where to go from here. If you want it to see it in action, [click here](http://myflashpics.com/mobile/picture/8ibjr).

Thanks!

Comment: The PHP code doesn't matter; post the HTML the client browser sees.

Comment: I know. That is the HTML that get's displayed. It's all in a simple echo. You mean you want to see a test picture?

Comment: @Jared Farrish: I changed the variables to something. Didn't change anything with the alignment or functionality, but I did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scratch the margin; add `bottom:15px;` and set `width:auto; left:20px; right:10px`

Comment: glad it helped. sorry for the short answer, i was being lazy. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want the caption at the bottom you need to modify your CSS for the margin and position in this way:

```
.individual_picture_caption_wrapper_three {
    margin: 0 0 7px 7px;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but when I add a left/right margin to the box, nothing happens. If I add `left: 7px;`, it hangs over the edge by 7 pixels on the right with `width: 100%`. Thoughts?

Comment: Why do you want to add left/right margin to the box? It fits perfectly without the left/right margin. Also you can remove the `float:left` from that rule as well - it's not needed with the `position:absolute`.